# Unable to cast left join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to add a feature to my search page. Basically, if a certain condition is true (based on joining with another table), then apply some CSS class. Here are my (simplified) models:

```
MyTable
int Key
string Someinfo1
string Someinfo2
string CssClass

SomeTable
int Key
string CssClass
```

Using LINQ, I wish to join the two tables and assign `SearchResult.CssClass = SomeTable.CssClass`. In reality, there is some logic used for this assignment.

```
var test = db.MyTable
    .GroupJoin(db.SomeTable,
                m => m.Key,
                s => s.Key,
                (m, s) => new {m, s})
    .SelectMany(x => x.h.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, y) => new MyTable
                {
                    Key = x.m.Key,
                    Someinfo1 = x.m.Someinfo1,
                    Someinfo2 = x.m.Someinfo2,
                    CssClass = y.CssClass
                }
```

This code breaks, giving the error

`The entity or complex type 'MyTable' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

If I simply change the casting `(x, y) => new MyTable` to create an anonymous type `(x, y) => new` then things work how I expect them to. Though, I need this to have a typed as `MyTable` to be compatible with the view that currently exists. Why does it break when trying to cast, when it works fine otherwise? Casting after the fact doesn't work either. Thanks in advance

EDIT: To clarify, `MyTable` maps to a database table with the exception of `CssClass`. I have configured EF to ignore that element

`modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Ignore(m => m.CssClass);`

The desired value for `MyTable.CssClass` comes from `SomeTable`.

DefaultIfEmpty() is used to include all entries in `MyTable`. There exist cases where a Key exists in `MyTable`, but not `SomeTable`

Comment: I'm having some trouble reading this. Is it your intention to do a group join on two tables to then project it back into an object of one of the tables? Because you're querying `db.MyTable` and then selecting into an object of type `MyTable`.

Comment: Also, what is `x.h.DefaultIfEmpty`? What does `h` have to do with it?

Comment: Added some information to the bottom of the question. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error says, you cannot create a *new* instance of an entity from within a query.

It appears you're trying to override a property of `MyTable` with a property from `SomeTable`.  One drawback to that solution is that the new `CssClass` value will be saved back to `MyTable` if the entity is saved (which ma be what you want, but it doesn't seem like it based on your usage).  If you *really* need to do this, you're going to have to hydrate the entities (e.g. with `ToList()`) and then loop to update the value with the value from the related entity.

Your best bet is probably going to be to create a type that is *independent* of your actual entity class that your views use rather than coupling the views to your entity class.  It adds some work to map between the two classes but you can avoid problems like the one you're facing.  One challenge I can already see with your data model - how do you know if the `CssClass` value should be saved back to `MyTable` or `SomeTable`?

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't make sense to do that huh. Laziness gets me again. I had been simply trying to find a workaround to creating another ViewModel, which is why I tried that `.Ignore` garbage above.

Comment: Unfortunately, any time you have a difference between your storage model and our view model it's best not to try and alter the storage model for use within the view.